# What are the higher order terms in the variance of asset price model?

Tags: brownian-motion, finance, variance

Looking into the asset price model and after taking logs and solving the expectation of this model I am wondering what the higher order terms would look like?

Here Yi ~ N(0,1) and E[Yi^2] < infinity

Var [μδt + σ[sqrt(δt)] Yi - 1/2(σ)^2 δt (Yi)^2] =

(σ)^2 δt + “higher order terms”

How do I solve for these higher order terms? What should they look like? (is it something to do with Taylor’s series?)

Comment: This question would be more pertinent would it be asked on https://quant.stackexchange.com/
You should also read our guidances on how to format maths, for instance : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Okay thank you ! @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj